# How to set foreign keys in sequelize

Tags: node.js, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I have an issue creating a foreign keys in my models.I have used sequelize-cli to create models and migrations.Below is my code..
I need to make a relationship between End_user and End_user_authorization model.But i can not see the relation in Dbeaver.What i am doing wrong.Kindly guide.

model/End_user

```
static associate(models) {
  // define association here


  End_user.hasOne(models.End_user_authorization,{
    foreignKey : 'userId',
    as:'End_user_authorization',
    onDelete:'CASCADE'
  });
   }
      };


End_user.init({
 firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
 middleName: DataTypes.STRING,
 lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
 nickName: DataTypes.STRING,
 email: DataTypes.STRING,
 mobileNumber: DataTypes.INTEGER,
 bloodGroup: DataTypes.STRING,
 fatherName: DataTypes.STRING,
 motherName: DataTypes.STRING,
 fingerPrints: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
 bForm: DataTypes.INTEGER
 }, {
sequelize,
modelName: 'End_user',
});
 return End_user;
};
```

model/End_user_authorization

```
   static associate(models) {
  // define association here
    End_user_authorization.belongsTo(models.End_user,{
      foreignKey : 'userId',
      onDelete : 'CASCADE'
  });

   }
  };
   End_user_authorization.init({
     userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     authCode: DataTypes.STRING,
     regDeviceId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     regDeviceName: DataTypes.STRING,
     expiry: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     ipAddress: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      {
       sequelize,
       modelName: 'End_user_authorization',
       });
        return End_user_authorization;
        };
```

migration/End_user_authorization

Ignore the ipAddress part in migration file

```
            'use strict';
          module.exports = {
           up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
            await queryInterface.createTable('End_user_authorizations', {
               id: {
                  allowNull: false,
                  autoIncrement: true,
                  primaryKey: true,
                  type: Sequelize.INTEGER
                   },
               userId: {
                  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
                 references: {
                      model: 'End_user',
                      key: 'id',
                             }
                        },
                authCode: {
                    type: Sequelize.STRING
                      },
                regDeviceId: {
                     type: Sequelize.INTEGER
                            },
                regDeviceName: {
                       type: Sequelize.STRING
                           },
                 expiry: {
                      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
                           },
                  ipAddress: {
                       type: Sequelize.STRING,
                       onDelete:'CASCADE',
                  references:{
                  model:'AllowedIp',
                  key:'ipAddress',
                  }
  },
  createdAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  },
  updatedAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE
     }
    });
  },
 down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
   await queryInterface.dropTable('End_user_authorizations');
}
 };
```

Comment: Lots of ORMs don't create foreign key constraints in the database when you create associations in the ORM. That *used* to the the case in Sequelize. I don't know whether that's still the case; I haven't used Sequelize in a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue.I am sharing becauseit may be helpful to anyone else.Just make sure you create a model first whose Pk will be used to make a relationship with other table....Lets say if you have two models users and posts.
You want to keep User_id in posts model.Make sure to create user model first.